# Javascript Date Comparison Strange Behavior

Tags: javascript, date

I have a function that computes a start date and an end date.

It then prints out this code:

```
   $log.log("currentDate: " + currentDate);
   $log.log("currentDate: " + startDate + " " + (currentDate.valueOf() > startDate.valueOf()));
   $log.log("currentDate: " + endDate + " " + (currentDate.valueOf() < endDate.valueOf()));
```

But in my console window, the comparisons return false, even when they should return true!

```
currentDate: Fri Mar 18 2016 14:09:26 GMT-0500 (CDT)angular.js:12722 
currentDate: Fri Mar 18 2016 08:00:26 GMT-0500 (CDT) false
currentDate: Fri Mar 18 2016 19:30:26 GMT-0500 (CDT) false
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try it without the `valueOf` calls

Comment: The following answers should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks. My issue had to do with not putting the "new" keyword when creating the current date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the complete context about your variables but I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K7ZaysA2ddBHIimHUD6n) and works as expected using only setTimeout. Please check how valueOf() is working as expected and giving **true**

```
var currentDate, endDate, startDate= new Date();

setTimeout(function(){
  currentDate = new Date();
}, 1000)
setTimeout(function(){
  endDate = new Date();
},2000)

setTimeout(function(){
  $log.log("currentDate: " + currentDate);
  $log.log("currentDate: " + startDate + " " + (currentDate.valueOf() > startDate.valueOf()));
  $log.log("currentDate: " + endDate + " " + (currentDate.valueOf() < endDate.valueOf()));
  $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
},3000);
```